# Impact of Cache-control header as request header

Tags: httprequest, cache-control, request-headers

I could see a lot of articles explaining about "Cache-Control" when it is used as a response header.
Could somebody explain me what is the impact when we use cache-control as a request header.

**Here is the scenario I'm trying to solve.**

In the environment I'm working,there is no way I can say not to cache the response in the response header. 
Everything is fine with this, but one of the requests doesn't need a cached response. This request is a synchronous ajax "GET" request. So,to make it not to use the cache I'm setting "Cache-Control" header in the request the following way.

```
var xhr = new XMLHTTPRequest();
xhr.open(..,...,false);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache");
xhr.send(null);
```

This is returning the response from the cache rather than making an explicit call to server.
So how can I make an ajax call that skips the cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One common trick is to send a timestamp parameter:

```
xhr.open(..,... + "?now=" + new Date().getTime(), false);
```

Comment: yeah.. that would solve but I'm interested in knowing how can we solve this by specifying the request headers..

Comment: I would also like to know, but it seems that every browser implements it differently, and many libraries like Dojo do this. See [here](http://ajaxpatterns.org/XMLHttpRequest_Call#How_will_caching_be_controlled.3F)